# PlaceAutoCompleteFragment in android not showing suggestions and closes after entering the first letter

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-android-api-2, google-places-api

The  autocomplete widget service in the `Google Places API` for Android is not working as expected. I have included the fragment in my xml page and also added the listener activity to my `onCreate()`. 
Then I start executing the autocomplete fragment, I click the first letter of the word I want to search and suddenly instead of showing suggestions the `onError()` gets executed and it closes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.akhil.maplocation.MapsActivity" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/place_autocomplete_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The mainactivity for this is:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    LatLng fromadd;
     @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
           PlaceAutocompleteFragment autocompleteFragment = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment)
                    getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment);


            autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
                    // TODO: Get info about the selected place.
                    fromadd = place.getLatLng();
                    double lat = fromadd.latitude;
                    double lng = fromadd.longitude;        
                    gotoLocation(lat, lng, 15);
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Status status) {
                    // TODO: Handle the error.
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"failure",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
                MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                markerOptions.position(latLng);
                fromadd = latLng;
                markerOptions.title(latLng.latitude + ":" + latLng.longitude + " " + latLng.toString());
                mMap.clear();
                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
                mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
            }
        });


        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

@Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {                
            return;
        }
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
```

}

Comment: what is the error ? log the error from the placeautocmplete and post the log here .

Comment: Status{statusCode=PLACES_API_ACCESS_NOT_CONFIGURED, resolution=null}

Comment: this might help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30434238/place-picker-automatically-close-after-launch

if this wont work inform me. i will post a full answer.

Comment: Nope.. That didn't work. For me it doesn't close immediately for me. It closes after I type the first character.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably miss an API key, which is required for use of Google Places API. Check out [this link](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/signup#api-console). When you do all things specified in the link, also add this code to your AndroidManifest

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="YOUR_KEY" />
```

Comment: I do have the API KEY code for the map. Should I create a new API KEY or can I use the same key?

Comment: I got this when i logged it: Status{statusCode=PLACES_API_ACCESS_NOT_CONFIGURED, resolution=null}

Comment: I think that API key should be ok. But make sure that you enable your application in developers console. There you have to supply your application package name and application's SHA-1. Check out link in answer for information about enabling application in developers console and [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15727912/sha-1-fingerprint-of-keystore-certificate) for information how to obtain SHA-1.

Answer (score 0):

mMap need to be initialied before use of mMap.setOnMapClickListener(.... ; the gotoLocation(lat,lng,15) has to look as below :

```
private void gotoLocation(double lat, double lng, int i) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub   

                 Marker myMarker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.home))
                .position(p1)
                .snippet("Lat:" + lat + "Lng:" + lng)
                .title("HOME"));

                 map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                        .findFragmentById(R.id.map2)).getMap();
                map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(lat, lng), i));                  
            }
```