# Google Places-API statusCode = PLACES_API_ACCESS_NOT_CONFIGURED

Tags: android, api, google-places-api, api-key, google-places

Im trying to implement Google-Places-API.
I generated an API-Key as described [here](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/signup) by copy/pasting the SHA1-Fingerprint from my "debug.keystore" into the corresponding field in  credentials.

As the Projectname i used the value of "applicationId" from my build.gradle.

Now I am trying to use AutoComplete from the API like:

```
Intent intent = new PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder(PlaceAutocomplete.MODE_OVERLAY).build(getTurActivity());
        startActivityForResult(intent, PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE);
```

When I print out the status in onActivityResult i get the Status (see title) and the Status-Code: 9003

I am aware that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31449649/android-google-places-api-getautocompletepredictions-returns-status-places-api) post exists but It didn't solve my problem.
I checked my credentials and the API key, and everything seems to be just fine.

In my manifest file i set the API key inside application like this:

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIz*********....***"/>
```

Comment: Enabling the Google Places API for Android in your Google Developer Console should solve your problem.

Comment: I did enable it - thats where i am confused. I did everything, that needed to be done.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after a lot of testing and googleing I got it to work - but I am still confused:

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30459990/3828593) and gave it a try, although I didn't believe it would help. When I got to my Module-Settings the only thing i did was to copy the Application Id without changing it (the exact same one, that I already copy/pasted from my build.gradle btw) and pasted it into field in the Developer Console. After that, it just worked.

I am quite certain that I already had used this exact same Application Id without success and i know I did everything that was needed to get it to working in my previous attempts - but this just magically did the trick.

As I said, I am still confused and would be really thankfull if someone could point out some possibilities of what could have gone wrong here - apart from that, my problem seems to be solved.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Google says it may take several minutes before the key is activated. perhaps you hadnt waited long enough?