# error code 9003, "places_api_access_not_configured" using google place api with android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api

I am using google map API to let users select location. Map is working fine. There is an error on getting autocomplete suggestion for location names. I have checked for configurations in google API console. Its all right.

Error code is 9003, places_api_access_not_configured

Complete error message is :
Error contacting API:
com.google.android.gms.tasks.RuntimeExcecutionException:
com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException:1009:
places_api_access_not_configured

build.gradle (module) is

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "package.name"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 11
    versionName "3.0.1"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    targetCompatibility 1.8
    sourceCompatibility 1.8
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
//noinspection GradleCompatible,GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
//noinspection GradleCompatible,GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.+'
implementation 'com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1'
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
implementation 'com.facebook.shimmer:shimmer:0.1.0@aar'
implementation 'net.cachapa.expandablelayout:expandablelayout:2.9.2'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0'


//google map
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.4.0'

}


configurations.all {
resolutionStrategy.force 'com.android.support:support- 
annotations:27.1.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

build.gradle (project) is

```
buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    //classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.+'


    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()

    maven{
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Code on map activity to get auto complete suggestions

```
private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener mAutocompleteClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

        InputMethodManager in = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        //in.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
        in.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getApplicationWindowToken(), 0);


        final AutocompletePrediction item = mPlaceAutocompleteAdapter.getItem(i);
        final String placeID = item.getPlaceId();

        PendingResult<PlaceBuffer> placeResult = Places.GeoDataApi
                .getPlaceById(mGoogleApiClient, placeID);

        placeResult.setResultCallback(mUpdatePlaceDetailsCallback);

    }
};


private ResultCallback<PlaceBuffer> mUpdatePlaceDetailsCallback = new ResultCallback<PlaceBuffer>() {
    @Override
    public void onResult(@NonNull PlaceBuffer places) {
        hideSoftKeyBoard();

        if (!places.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onResult: Place query did not complete successfully!" + places.getStatus().toString());
            places.release();
            return;
        }

        final Place place = places.get(0);


        try {
            mPlace = new PlaceInfo();
            mPlace.setName(place.getName().toString());
            mPlace.setAddress(place.getAddress().toString());
            //mPlace.setAttributions(place.getAttributions().toString());
            mPlace.setId(place.getId());
            mPlace.setLatLng(place.getLatLng());
            mPlace.setRating(place.getRating());
            mPlace.setPhoneNumber(place.getPhoneNumber().toString());
            mPlace.setWebsiteUri(place.getWebsiteUri());

            LatLng latLng = place.getLatLng();

            LattitudeToRetun = String.valueOf(latLng.latitude);
            LongitudeToRetun = String.valueOf(latLng.longitude);

            getAddressFromLatLong(latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude);

            Log.d(TAG, "onResult: Place details : " + mPlace.toString());
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onResult: NullPointerException : " + e.getMessage());
        }

        //moveCamera(mPlace.getLatLng(), DEFAULT_ZOOM, mPlace.getName());

        moveCamera(new LatLng(place.getViewport().getCenter().latitude, place.getViewport().getCenter().longitude)
                , DEFAULT_ZOOM, mPlace);

        places.release();
    }
};
```

manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="package.name">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

<application
    android:name=".MyApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:roundIcon="@drawable/logo_500"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_map_API_key" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <service android:name=".Utils.MyFirebaseInstanceIdService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <service android:name=".Utils.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <receiver
        android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver> 

    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.igkv.customhiring.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
    </provider>

    <activity
        android:name=".Activity.DefaultActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:theme="@style/MyTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Place Picker Automatically close after launch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30434238/place-picker-automatically-close-after-launch)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not Enabled the Google Places API for Android in developers console. Enable it and check .

[Click Here](https://console.developers.google.com/) for Google Console link .

Comment: Google Places API is enabled for the particular project

Comment: Try Enabling both places API as well as Places sdk